# Configuring IDREFS-type element for JAXB Marshalling

Tags: jaxb

I've got a JAXB class with an IDREFS attribute.  For creating and marshaling an instance, I'd like to 'set' the value of the attribute directly (as a string that represents the space-separated list of IDREFs) instead of setting the value to the list of objects that the IDREFS refer to.  So I'd be setting the IDs directly and JAXB would resolve the IDREFS on its own should it need to (there isn't actually a need to resolve the IDREFs to their target objects since I'm only using the document for marshaling, not unmarshaling).  Can JAXB do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the IDs yourself (instead of having JAXB resolve them) you can just not annotate it with `@XmlIDREF`.  To get a list to appear space separated in a single attribute or element simply annotate it the `@XmlList`.